# Is it possible to change the contact email address on a Google Apps for Work account?

Tags: google-apps-for-work

I set up a Google Apps for Work account for a friend.  I would like to change the contact email from my address to hers.

The instructions say

> To add a contact email:
>
> 1. Sign in to My Account.
> 2. In the "Personal info & privacy" section, 
>         select Your personal info and then Email.
> 3. Choose Advanced, then Contact email.
> 4. Add your contact email address.
> 5. Check your inbox for your verification email and select Verify.

But there is no 'Advanced' option, or any option to edit the Contact email.  I can change the Recovery email but that's it.  Is there any way to do this?

Alternatively, if I were to delete the whole thing and start again, would I be able to set up Google Apps for Work with the same domain name?

Comment: I thought it was the contact email address because I was recieving notifications there.  Turns out it was the secondary email address (see answer)

Answer (score 2):

I logged a support ticket with Google and got an answer.
The place to log a support ticket is here:
https://support.google.com/a/topic/7067151?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=2412034

It wasn't the *contact* email address I needed to change it was the *secondary* email address.  This can be found in the Admin Console under Company Profile > Profile > Contact Information > Secondary Email address.